# Algorithm integration in .r file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I need to integrate an analytical algorithm contained in a .r file into a client server architecture. What libraries or apis, or another programming strategy can I use? Could you explain briefly how this integration works?
Thanks for the help, because I do not know what to use.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: bfontaine, 

I did not start an implementation, I know that the R extension is a programming language used for statistical analysis and graphics, I'm thinking of doing SignalR but would like some suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute local R script via R.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345459/execute-local-r-script-via-r-net)