# How to run R script in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, r, statistics

Hope all are doing good.

I have a script, need to execute in Visual Studio using C# by R.NET

I have tried below things

**Trial 1:**

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\rfile2.R"))
                {
                    engine.Evaluate(fs);
                }
```

Output : Not working Error : Error in Application

**Trial 2:**

```
engine.Evaluate(("source(\"D:/rfile2.R\")"));
```

Output : Not working Error : Error in Application

Comment: Maybe there is an error inside R script?

Comment: @pwas No..It is working fine in R studio.. I am able to execute there

Comment: Unfortunately, at this moment - nope.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) in conjunction with

```
Rscript --slave D:/rfile2.R
```

Comment: ..please Can you explain bit more ?

Comment: Just run the R script as a system command rather than directly from C# -- or do you somehow need to interact with its output?

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224439/run-r-script-with-start-process-in-net   but not working

Comment: I tried this now string strCmdText = "Rscript D:/rfile2.R";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText); Not working