# How to pass variables created in R to a c# application?

Tags: c#, r

I have created a console application in C# inorder to execute a R program using Rscript.exe. This is working fine. I was wondering if there is a method that would allow me to capture the variables that are created in the R script? What I'm currently doing is taking the output created in the Cmd and then doing some string management. But it's a cumbersome method.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I ues Jake Drew's solution here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224439/run-r-script-with-start-process-in-net/24378475#24378475

Comment: Why not use R.NET? It's really easy and straightforward. http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/