# Executing .R script with RGL Plott from c# Gui via RScripRunner Class

Tags: c#, .net, r, rgl, r.net

I have a PointCloud with XYZ-Data and want to plot it via a .r script from my C# GUI. Therefore i use the "rgl" library in R. The R code works fine. I try to use this class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class runs R code from a file using the console.
/// </summary>
public class RScriptRunner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs an R script from a file using Rscript.exe.
    /// Example:  
    ///   RScriptRunner.RunFromCmd(curDirectory + @"\ImageClustering.r", "rscript.exe", curDirectory.Replace('\\','/'));
    /// Getting args passed from C# using R:
    ///   args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
    ///   print(args[1]);
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rCodeFilePath">File where your R code is located.</param>
    /// <param name="rScriptExecutablePath">Usually only requires "rscript.exe"</param>
    /// <param name="args">Multiple R args can be seperated by spaces.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a string with the R responses.</returns>
    public static string RunFromCmd(string rCodeFilePath, string rScriptExecutablePath, string args)
    {
            string file = rCodeFilePath;
            string result = string.Empty;

            try
            {

                var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.FileName = rScriptExecutablePath;
                info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(rScriptExecutablePath);
                info.Arguments = rCodeFilePath + " " + args;

                info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;

                using (var proc = new Process())
                {
                    proc.StartInfo = info;
                    proc.Start();
                    result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    proc.Close();
                }

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("R Script failed: " + result, ex);
            }
    }
}
```

I copied it from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224439/run-r-script-with-start-process-in-net/53054499#53054499](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224439/run-r-script-with-start-process-in-net/53054499#53054499)

The problem is when i start the .r file via the RScriptRunner-Class from above, the rgl-plot pops out, and directly shut down. So what can i do that the plot window stays open? 
Here my .R code:

```
daten <- read.csv("file:///C:\\Users\\Quirin\\Dropbox\\KwiJuLa\\Testmessung Debugging 25.10\\test.csv")

library(rgl)

datenMatrix <- as.matrix(daten)
x1 <- datenMatrix[, 3]
y1 <- datenMatrix[, 4]
z1 <- datenMatrix[, 5]


rgl1 <- plot3d(x1, y1, z1)
```

Kindly Regards

Comment: I don't know c# at all, but the likely cause it that is is running R only for a short duration.  You need to keep R running as long as you want to view the rgl scene.

Comment: Okay i see. But do u know how to do that?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone who knows C#.

Comment: Another idea:  use `rglwidget()` to write out a web page, and display your image in a browser window.

Comment: I will try this!